# eglot - javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set up eglot on ubuntu and emacs 26.1.  I have installed version 1.4

When I run `M-x eglot` I get:

```
[eglot] I guess you want to run `javascript-typescript-stdio', but I can't find `javascript-typescript-stdio' in PATH!
```

However I can't find anything about it in the instructions.  Does anybody know what I have to install to make it work.

When I follow the link it takes me to a low level package that doesn't seem to correspond to an npm package.

Comment: FWIW: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/a96nzz/cant_find_the_command_in_path/

Comment: Looks like you want to install https://github.com/sourcegraph/javascript-typescript-langserver

Comment: yeah I found that too, but it only has instructions for installing from source, so still looking for confirmation that that is the recommended way

Comment: that post is different.  they have it installed on the command line, but emacs can't find it.  I don't know how to install it on the command line

Comment: I don't write JS too much, but I think you should first install the language server, take a look at [Using Language Servers in Neovim - fortes.com](https://fortes.com/2017/language-server-neovim/):
> First, we need to install a Language Server for JavaScript, we’ll use javascript-typescript-langserver which you can install via Yarn by running yarn global add javascript-typescript-langserver (or npm install -g javascript-typescript-langserver if you’re still on npm).

Then make sure that the directory for the executable `javascript-typescript-stdio` is in `exec-path` of Emacs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use `lsp` for javascript you have to install its corresponding `lsp-server` e.g. `javascript-typescript-langserver`.

If you have `node` and `npm` already installed you can just install the package globally:

```
npm install -g javascript-typescript-langserver
```

If you don't have `node` already installed I suggest using `nvm`. [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is a command line tool that lets you manage your node version. If you use it you can install different versions of node or control the exact version you want to use.

If you don't want to use `nvm` you can download and install node from the [official site](https://nodejs.org/en/).